# Konva Text : While using emoji in text, it renders as a line text instead of a filled emoji

Tags: konvajs

let complexText = new Konva.Text({
x: 0,
y: 0,
text: " hello World ",
fontSize: 12,
fill: "#003049",
width: stage.width() - 10,
padding: 5,
align: "center",[Received output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzXjL.png)
});

Expected Output: hello World

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Emoji's are not available in all fonts. Look on the web for lists of emoji fonts such as: https://typography.guru/list/topic/emoji-fonts/.

But be aware that the emoji font maybe will not also provide letter characters - it might just be smileys only. You will have to create text nodes for each of the emojis and the text segments.